# Python with Selenium - Cannot find and click this specific element due to randomization of it's location on the site

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, element

I've been creating a tool that plays through an online game using python 2.7 and selenium, and am very stuck on one particular element I need to select.

The UI looks as follows:

```
1   2   3
a   d   g
b   e   h
c   f   i
```

The numbers one two and three represent a drop down menu, which when clicked open up the letters. Each option represents a different outcome. The problem is, at the start of each game the positions of both the numbers and letters are randomized. In the code, each button's css selector is labeled as for example "#action-1 > button:nth-child(1)", as in the "first button", but the "first button" will be different every game.

**I've tried finding by link text, xpath, and css selector to no success.**

If it helps, pressing "copy outer html" gives this:

```
<button class="ng-binding" ng-click="subBtn($event)" ng-class="{disabled : !state.chapterStart || state.btns.indexOf(btn.action) != -1}" ng-disabled="!state.chapterStart || state.btns.indexOf(btn.action) != -1">Wait and See What They Do</button>
```

The "Wait and See What They Do" part of it is what the button says and is how you know what to click, but I can't seem to find the element by that.

Copying the xpath results in //*[@id="action-1"]/button, which again isn't really helpful because telling it to click that would just be like saying "click the button that is in the first position", and it changes every time. I've added long time.sleep() commands to test, the page is definitely loading all the way so that is not the issue.

Anyways, I've been trying to figure this one out for way too long and it has me stumped. I'd be very grateful for any input you all can give. Thank you!

Comment: Would you post a link to the online game? I'd like to see it... this sounds like an interesting problem.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still in development and is hosted on a private server at the moment. I can give you a specific snipet of the code if it will help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to locate an element by the text it contains you can use XPath. You stated that you tried XPath but no specifics were given. Did you try the below? It should work given the HTML you provided.

```
//button[text()='Wait and See What They Do']
```

To read this XPath... find any descendant `//` that is a `BUTTON` tag that has an attribute `[]` where the text contained in the element is equal to the search string, `text()=''`.

Another example might be the below which is an alternate way to find your button. The problem with this way is that there may be many buttons on the page with that class so it may not be specific enough.

```
//button[@class='ng-binding']
```

I've found (and others have also) that XPaths are generally slower than other location methods. Because of this, I generally prefer By.Id, when available, then By.CssSelector. They are both significantly faster than XPath. I save XPath for things like finding text in an element or finding relative elements (CSS can do this some but is no where near as powerful as XPath).

[XPath Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That returned the error: InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression "//button[text()='Wait and See What They Do'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression. When I try to just copy xpath with chrome, it just gives "//*[@id="action-1"]/button", and that just chooses the button that happens to be in the first position... I feel this problem will be more tough to crack than I thought.

Comment: In case it helps, the command I am using is     browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Wait and See What They Do']").click()

Comment: That's really odd. I thought maybe you mistyped something but the code looks good. If I paste `$x("//button[text()='Wait and See What They Do']")` into the Chrome dev console, it doesn't give me an error that it's an invalid XPath.

Comment: Is it possible that you need a wait? Maybe the element isn't immediately available but that still wouldn't explain why you are getting the SyntaxError.

Comment: When I used the xpath //*[@id="action-1"]/button, it would work perfectly so I just assumed that time wasn't an issue. Adding a wait to your fix worked perfectly!!! I cannot thank you enough, hot damn! Do you mind if I ask how you found that xpath on that specific piece of code I gave you? I'm not actually sure how to read an xpath and figure that out, I've just been copying whatever is available. Again, holy crap thank you so much!

Comment: I've been doing automation for a long time. More recently I started using Selenium and ran across XPaths. My first reaction was negative so I stayed away from them and used mainly CSS selectors but there are some things like this example of finding text inside an element that only XPath can do. So... long story short, I've been learning more XPath. I read XPath articles and google a lot. I also troll the questions here on SO and see a lot of this stuff so I've been learning as I go. I definitely have a lot left to learn around XPaths...

Comment: I updated my answer to give a little more explanation of how to read the XPath along with some references you can check out.

Comment: Marked it as the answer, apparently I don't have enough reputation yet to publicly upvote it yet though. Did it nonetheless, thank you for your help!